# What can go wrong if we do NOT follow RESTful best practices?

Tags: rest, api, http, caching, proxy

<sup>***TL;DR : scroll down to the last paragraph.***</sup>

There is a lot of talk about best practices when defining RESTful APIs: what HTTP methods to support, which HTTP method to use in each case, which HTTP status code to return, when to pass parameters in the query string vs. in the path vs. in the content body vs. in the headers, how to do versioning, result set limiting, pagination, etc.

If you are already determined to make use of best practices, there are lots of questions and answers out there about what is the best practice for doing any given thing. Unfortunately, there appears to be no question (nor answer) as to ***why*** use best practices in the first place.

Most of the best practice guidelines direct developers to follow the principle of least surprise, which, under normal circumstances, would be a good enough reason to follow them.  Unfortunately, REST-over-HTTP is a capricious standard, the best practices of which are impossible to implement without becoming intimately involved with it, and the drawback of intimate involvement is that you tend to end up with your application being very tightly bound to a particular transport mechanism. So, some people (like me) are debating whether the benefit of "least surprise" justifies the drawback of littering the application with REST-over-HTTP concerns.

A different approach examined as an alternative to best practices suggests that our involvement with HTTP should be limited to the bare minimum necessary in order to get an application-defined payload from point A to point B.  According to this approach, you only use a single REST entry point URL in your entire application, you never use any HTTP method other than HTTP POST, never return any HTTP status code other than HTTP 200 OK, and never pass any parameter in any way other than within the application-specific payload of the request. The request will either fail to be delivered, in which case it is the responsibility of the web server to return an "HTTP 404 Not Found" to the client, or it will be successfully delivered, in which case the delivery of the request was "HTTP 200 OK" as far as the transport protocol is concerned, and anything else that might go wrong from that point on is exclusively an application concern, and none of the transport protocol's business.  Obviously, this approach is kind of like saying "let me show you where to stick your best practices".

Now, there are other voices that say that things are not that simple, and that if you do not follow the RESTful best practices, things will break.

The story goes that for example, in the event of unauthorized access, you should return an actual "HTTP 401 Unauthorized" (instead of a successful response containing a json-serialized UnauthorizedException) because upon receiving the 401, the browser will prompt the user of credentials.  Of course this does not really hold any water, because REST requests are not issued by browsers being used by human users.

Another, more sophisticated way the story goes is that usually, between the client and the server exist proxies, and these proxies inspect HTTP requests and responses, and try to make sense out of them, so as to handle different requests differently.  For example, they say, somewhere between the client and the server there may be a caching proxy, which may treat all requests to the exact same URL as identical and therefore cacheable.  So, path parameters are necessary to differentiate between different resources, otherwise the caching proxy might only ever forward a request to the server once, and return cached responses to all clients thereafter. Furthermore, this caching proxy may need to know that a certain request-response exchange resulted in a failure due to a particular error such as "Permission Denied", so as to again not cache the response, otherwise a request resulting in a temporary error may be answered with a cached error response forever.

So, my questions are:

Besides "familiarity" and "least surprise", what other good reasons are there for following REST best practices?  Are these concerns about proxies real?  Are caching proxies really so dumb as to cache REST responses?  Is it hard to configure the proxies to behave in less dumb ways?  Are there drawbacks in configuring the proxies to behave in less dumb ways?

Comment: "because REST requests are not issued by browsers being used by human users" - of course they are, all the time -- it seems you are confusing REST with any way to do RPCs over HTTP.

Comment: @JulianReschke How are REST requests being issued by human users using web browsers? If you are talking about web sites that run javascript which uses REST for communication with the server, have you seen any such web sites that actually allow a 401 to be handled by the browser resulting in a browser-generated authentication dialog?  (I haven't.)

Comment: it would become RESTless.

Comment: How is using GET to obtain hypermedia forms, filling them out, and POSTing them back *not* "restful"?

Answer (score 2):

It's worth considering that what you're suggesting is the way that HTTP APIs used to be designed for a good 15 years or so. API designers are tending to move away from that approach these days. They really do have their reasons.

Some points to consider if you want to avoid using ReST over HTTP:

- ReST over HTTP is an efficient use of the HTTP/S transport mechanism. Avoiding the ReST paradigm runs the risk of every request / response being wrapped in verbose envelopes. SOAP is an example of this.
- ReST encourages client and server decoupling by putting application semantics into standard mechanisms - HTTP and XML/JSON (or others data formats). These protocols and standards are well supported by standard libraries and have been built up over years of experience. Sure, you **can** create your own 'unauthorized' response body with a 200 status code, but ReST frameworks just make it unnecessary so why bother?
- ReST is a design approach which encourages a view of your distributed system which focuses on data rather than functionality, and this has a proven a useful mechanism for building distributed systems. Avoiding ReST runs the risk of focusing on very RPC-like mechanisms which have some risks of their own:

  - they can become very fine-grained and 'chatty'
  - which can be an inefficient use of network bandwidth
  - which can tightly couple client and server, through introducing stateful-ness and temporal coupling beteween requests.
  - and can be difficult to scale horizontally
    Note: there are times when an RPC approach is actually a better way of breaking down a distributed system than a resource-oriented approach, but they tend to be the exceptions rather than the rule.
- existing tools for developers make debugging / investigations of ReSTful APIs easier. It's easy to use a browser to do a simple GET, for example. And tools such as Postman or RestClient already exist for more complex ReST-style queries. In extreme situations tcpdump is very useful, as are browser debugging tools such as firebug. If every API call has application layer semantics built on top of HTTP (e.g. special response types for particular error situations) then you immediately lose some value from some of this tooling. Building SOAP envelopes in PostMan is a pain. As is reading SOAP response envelopes.
- network infrastructure around caching really can be as dumb as you're asking. It's possible to get around this but you really do have to think about it and it will inevitably involve increased network traffic in some situations where it's unnecessary. And caching responses for repeated queries is one way in which APIs scale out, so you'll likely need to 'solve' the problem yourself (i.e. reinvent the wheel) of how to cache repeated queries.

Having said all that, if you want to look into a pure message-passing design for your distributed system rather than a ReSTful one, why consider HTTP at all? Why not simply use some message-oriented middleware (e.g. RabbitMQ) to build your application, possibly with some sort of HTTP bridge somewhere for Internet-based clients? Using HTTP as a pure transport mechanism involving a simple 'message accepted / not accepted' semantics seems overkill.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer.  Unfortunately, for me, it opens up new questions at a rate of about one new question per paragraph.  (And we do not want this to turn into a forum-like discussion.)

Answer (score 1):

*REST is intended for long-lived network-based applications that span multiple organizations. If you don’t see a need for the constraints, then don’t use them. -- Roy T Fielding*

> Unfortunately, there appears to be no question (nor answer) as to why use best practices in the first place.

When in doubt, go back to the source

[Fielding's dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation.pdf) really does quite a good job at explaining how the REST architectural constraints ensure that you don't destroy the properties those constraints are designed to protect.

Keep in mind - before the web (which is the reference application for REST), "web scale" wasn't a thing; the notion of a generic client (the browers) that could discover and consume thousands of customized applications (provided by web servers) had not previously been realized.

> According to this approach, you only use a single REST entry point URL in your entire application, you never use any HTTP method other than HTTP POST, never return any HTTP status code other than HTTP 200 OK, and never pass any parameter in any way other than within the application-specific payload of the request.

Yup - that's a thing, it's called RPC; you are effectively taking the web, and stripping it down to a bare message transport application that just happens to tunnel through port 80.

In doing so, you have stripped away the uniform interface -- you've lost the ability to use commodity parts in your deployment, because nobody can participate in the conversation unless they share the same interpretation of the message data.

Note: that's doesn't at all imply that RPC is "broken"; architecture is about tradeoffs.  The RPC approach gives up some of the value derived from the properties guarded by REST, but that doesn't mean it doesn't pick up value somewhere else.  Horses for courses.

> Besides "familiarity" and "least surprise", what other good reasons are there for following REST best practices?

Cheap scaling of reads - as your offering becomes more popular, you can service more clients by installing a farm of commodity reverse-proxies that will serve cached representations where available, and only put load on the server when no fresh representation is available.

Prefetching - if you are adhering to the safety provisions of the interface, agents (and intermediaries) know that they can download representations at their own discretion without concern that the operators will be liable for loss of capital.  AKA - your resources can be crawled (and cached)

Similarly, use of idempotent methods (where appropriate) communicates to agents (and intermediaries) that retrying the send of an unacknowledged message causes no harm (for instance, in the event of a network outage).

Independent innovation of clients and servers, especially cross organizations.  Mosaic is a museum piece, Netscape vanished long ago, but the web is still going strong.

> Of course this does not really hold any water, because REST requests are not issued by browsers being used by human users.

Of course they are -- where do you think you are reading this answer?

So far, REST works really well at exposing capabilities to human agents; which is to say that the server side is so ubiquitous at this point that we hardly think about it any more.  The notion that you -- the human operator -- can use the same application to order pizza, run diagnostics on your house, and remote start your car is as normal as air.

But you are absolutely right that replacing the human still seems a long ways off; there are various standards and media types for communicating semantic content of data -- the automated client can look at markup, identify a phone number element, and provide a customized array of menu options from it -- but building into agents the sorts of fuzzy intelligence needed to align offered capabilities with goals, or to recover from error conditions, seems to be a ways off.